# How to import Chrome passwords into iCloud Keychain

Tags: icloud, keychain

Latest MacOS release (10.15.4) [added](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2020/03/safari-macos-catalina-import-google-chrome-passwords-icloud-keychain.html) the following option:

> Option to import Chrome passwords into your iCloud Keychain for easy AutoFill of your passwords in Safari and across all your devices

Where do I find the settings for this / how to actually achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Finally found it. It's in Safari menu. Too bad it seems like a one-off action instead of true sharing of this data:

[image]

Then:

[image]